# [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds gives incorrect value

Tags: objective-c, uiscreen

I'm building a landscape app in Xcode 6. When I run it on the iOS 8.3 simulator, `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` is `667x375`, but when I run it on an iPhone 6 iOS 8, `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` is `375x667`. This is causing problems for my app as many elements are sized with the screen bounds. I know `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds` changed in iOS 8, but that's not the issue. It should be `667x375` on both the device and simulator.
I'd provide code, but I have no idea where the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

```
iOS 8.3 iPhone6 Simulator
    Portlait
                           bounds:{{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
                 applicationFrame:{{0, 20}, {375, 647}}
                     nativeBounds:{{0, 0}, {750, 1334}}

    Landscape
                           bounds:{{0, 0}, {667, 375}}
                 applicationFrame:{{0, 0}, {667, 375}}
                     nativeBounds:{{0, 0}, {750, 1334}}

iOS 8.3 iPhone6 Device
    Portlait
                           bounds:{{0, 0}, {375, 667}}
                 applicationFrame:{{0, 20}, {375, 647}}
                     nativeBounds:{{0, 0}, {750, 1334}}
    Landscape
                           bounds:{{0, 0}, {667, 375}}
                 applicationFrame:{{0, 0}, {667, 375}}
                     nativeBounds:{{0, 0}, {750, 1334}}
```

On iOS 8.3, the simulator and device's results are exactly same. If reported situation only occurs on the iOS 8 device, how about targeting your application to iOS 8.3 ?

Comment: This was my experience also (on iOS 8.1.3, 8.2, and 8.3).

Answer (score 0):

On iOS8, the window's frame will change as the device orientation. I think 667x375 is the size when your device is landscape.

Comment: Then why does my iPhone 6 NSLog that the orientation is `375x667` while running the app with no changes on the iPhone 6 simulator NSLogs `667x375`?

Comment: May be your  simulator is landscape on one 6+ and portrait on 6. Please try to adjust your simulator's orientation by cmd+left/right.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my simulator is in landscape. The app actually works fine in the simulator, but not the device. The physical device is what seems to be giving incorrect bounds.

Comment: Are your trying to get the value in viewDidLoad or something similar? The value is invalid at that time. If so, you should get the correct bounds in viewDidLayoutSubviews or viewDidAppear.

Comment: Im trying to use the screen bounds to set my view size. The view ends up "portrait" even though the device is landscape (due to the weird bounds).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a quick class method I use to change the screen size back to what it was before iOS 8 (switch height and width)

```
+ (CGSize)getScreenSize {

    CGSize screenSizeRef = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

    if (screenSizeRef.width > 450 && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() != UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // iPhone 6+ width on portrait is 414
        return CGSizeMake(screenSizeRef.height, screenSizeRef.width);

    }

    if (screenSizeRef.width > 900 && UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {

        return CGSizeMake(screenSizeRef.height, screenSizeRef.width);

    }
    return screenSizeRef;
}
```

So instead of calling `[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]`, put this method in a new class (so you can access it from anywhere in the program) and set your screen size reference to the return value of `getScreenSize`